# Can I merge SQL Server tables if they have not exactly the same structure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, merge

I have two tables, `source` and `target`.

`source`:

```
+--------+------+-------------+
|  Name  | Year |    City     |
+--------+------+-------------+
| Toyota | 2002 | Los Angeles |
| Seat   | 2012 | Madrid      |
+--------+------+-------------+
```

`target`:

```
+----+---------+------+----------+
| ID |  Name   | Year |   City   |
+----+---------+------+----------+
|  1 | Bentley | 1969 | Budapest |
|  2 | Toyota  | 1988 | New York |
|  3 | Ford    | 2001 | Tokyo    |
|  4 | Seat    | 1995 | Madrid   |
|  5 | Bugatti | 1995 | London   |
+----+---------+------+----------+
```

I want to merge `source` into `target`. I know the `MERGE` command, it's fine. The issue is that the `source` has no column `ID` so that it won't match.

Since `Name` column in both are unique I only need to match if they are equal, then if not exists insert into target, if exists update target.

I could do it using `NOT EXIST` statement, but we are talking about billions of rows so MERGE would be a much quicker solution.

So can I somehow set the `MERGE` command to take only that column into account when matching?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can:

```
MERGE target t
USING source s
  ON t.name = s.name
WHEN NOT MATCHED 
  INSERT (Name, Year, City)
  VALUES (s.Name, s.Year, s.City)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET Year = s.Year,
             City = s.City;
```

If your `ID` column in target is not `IDENTITY` column you can create sequence to populate it.

Comment: Thanks. One bonus question: Are these inserts and updates trigger triggers set on target table?

Comment: @fishmong3r Do you want to fire updated in trigger every time? It is possible and should be added on source table, but you should think about performance impact. Perhaps job and loading data in schedule will be sufficient.

Comment: No. If for e.g. an update happens via the merge then I need to fire a trigger on target. Source has nothing to do with it.

Comment: @fishmong3r **source => target**. Changes from source need to be transferred to target, not vice versa. So trigger on source table.

Comment: You don't see my point. Source is only a temporary table. It's being dropped  right after the above `MERGE` script. What I say is that I have already existing triggers on `target`. So if I run the above script it will for e.g. update row `ID 2`. Will this update fire the trigger set on the `target` table?

Comment: @fishmong3r I see only what you posted in your question. Feel free to adjust it to your needs.

Comment: OK, I will post a separate question then.